# External URL for a Notification Button - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a button that creates a notification in my controller when I click it using the image_submit_tag, and I was wondering if there was a way to create an external URL from this button. For example, if I share said URL, the notification is automatically added upon click.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I currently have a notification button that adds a notification when I click on it. Is it possible to create a link that will automatically "click that notification button" for me when I open the link?

Comment: I still quite don't get it. Do you have a form with a button that creates a notification (whatever that means)? And you would like to create the same notification by clicking only a link, not the button?

Comment: So the button that creates the notification calls the create function in a corresponding controller which adds the notification to the respective user. And yes, I was wondering if I could induce the same effect by clicking only a link. Thanks again.